# Translate a word from a PDF file

Tags: pdf

When I read a PDF file I'd like to select a word and translate
it to a different language.

Do anyone know if there is a PDF reader or a PDF plugin for Acrobat that
can do that?

Answer (score 2):

In [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) this can be acomplished by making use of the built-in search facility.

[PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) has a number of predefined search engines (Google, Bing, ...) which can be called for the selected word via context menu. To get a translation, you can add your own "search engine" `URL` which points to a dictionary service.

My favorite dictionary is `www.leo.org`
To define *Leo* as new search engine, look up "TEST" in the dictionary site and copy the resulting URL. In case of Leo, this is

```
http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=TEST&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on
```

You can then paste this `URL` in the [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) dialog for defining new search engines.